# qgis (segment (link) start node and end node id's extraction from shapefile )

Tags: qgis

I have been dealing with a lot of shape files editing tools last month..
I tried to get two dbf files from shape file (one for nodes and one for links) in an appropriate format (node_id,x,y for nodes and link_id,start_node_id,end_node_id,...for links)in order to create  an oracle spatial network.
I got the dbf for nodes..
I want now to get the attribute table from a loaded shape file containing polylines (roads) and I want to split each polyline to its segments containing their start and end node id's besides their geometry..
Every help accepted..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clarify your question slightly, but it sounds like you want to get the details of each point in a polyline from a shapefile so that you can define segments.

I wrote an example of how you can do this using Python here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40798/how-to-split-shapefile-per-feature-in-python-using-gdal

Specifically, pay attention to the lines:

```
line = geom.asPolyline()
        # all points in the line
        for point in line:
```

You should be able to achieve your goal using a variation of this basic example.

Dan